# What new method does Rails' "has_many :through" generate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am establishing an associated relationship between models for house buying and selling. User will have plural Housing agencies and plural Houses, and conversely, House will also have plural Housing agencies and plural Users. The specific models are as follows:
model User

```
has_many :agencies
has_many :houses through: :agencies
```

model Agency

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :house
```

model House

```
has_many :agencies
has_many :users through: :agencies
```

I want to know, if I want to query the users who have joined the agency, can I do this

```
House.where(id: 10).agency_users
```

That is, will the `agency_users` method be generated? If yes, where is the official teaching document written? If not, how should it be fixed?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with you have an error in the definition of your assocation - `through` is a [keyword argument](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ruby-2-keyword-arguments) so you need to add a colon:

```
has_many :houses through: :agencies
```

> What new method does Rails' "has_many :through" generate?

It generates a whole bunch of methods:

```txt
                                  |       |          | has_many
generated methods                 | habtm | has_many | :through
----------------------------------+-------+----------+----------
others                            |   X   |    X     |    X
others=(other,other,...)          |   X   |    X     |    X
other_ids                         |   X   |    X     |    X
other_ids=(id,id,...)             |   X   |    X     |    X
others<<                          |   X   |    X     |    X
# ...
```

I don't know where you got `agency_users` from but its definately not going to be generated from any of the code in your question as its based on the name argument (the first one).

You're also making a classic rookie misstake and calling an assocation method on an ActiveRecord assocation. `where` returns multiple records while the assocations create instance methods. Use `find(10)` or `find_by(id: 10)` (if it should be allowed to be nil).

> If yes, where is the official teaching document written? If not, how should it be fixed?

I'm not sure what you're actually asking here or what "official teaching document" is supposed to mean. Rails has both [API documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) and [guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association).

If you're talking about documenting your own code it depends on if you're using RDoc or Yard. Neither will actually automatically pick up the methods generated by the assocation macros as far as I know but you can do it manually in Yard with:

```ruby
# @!method foo
```

I don't know if RDoc has a similiar feature so you might to just document the assocations in the overall class description.

### These assocations are not what you really want

The main problem here is that you're putting `house_id` on the agencies table which means that it can only ever record a single value per agency! Thats not going to be good for buisness.

What you actually want is something more like

```ruby
class Listing
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :agency
end

class Agency
  has_many :listings
  has_many :clients, 
    through: :listings,
    source: :user
end

class User
  has_many :listings
  has_many :agencies, 
    through: :listings
end
```

I would generally avoid the term House and go with the domain specific listing which can cover many different kinds of properties.

Comment: why ```source: :user```

Comment: Because the association is called clients and not users.

Comment: why the association is called client?

Comment: what is ```other_ids``` means?

Comment: Because that's what a real estate agency calls it's customers. You should probably do some basic research into the domain.

Comment: `other_ids` is a getter method that returns an array of the IDs of the associated records. It's roughly equivalent to `others.pluck(:id)`.